# Is there a way to install Windows after Ubuntu BUT AVOID overwriting grub?

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, windows

I understand that there are a lot of questions out there about installing these two os alongside, but I wonder if there is any other way to install Windows while not removing grub. This is really annoying to recover grub after installing windows. To be more specific, I am using Ubuntu, and I want to install newest Windwos 10

Comment: If you install Windows to a separate drive (HDD, SSD) when the Ubuntu drive is not connected, you will get two independent systems. In most computers you can select which one to boot via a hotkey, that brings up a boot menu. If you cannot have two internal drives, you can let Windows reside in the internal drive and install Ubuntu into an external drive, connected via eSATA or USB 3.

Comment: @TJY after installing Windows are you expecting grub menu to select windows? Or you want two drives and setting boot priority from BIOS Settings?

Comment: In UEFI systems with the original OS in the same mode you can install all other OSes you want and have all their bootloaders co-exist in the EFI partiton and each OS can be booted directly and independently from UEFI settings. No overwrite. I really don't know why the answers assume you're using an old BIOS machine. Unfortunately it's a theme, lots of ignorant questions and answers about dual-booting.

Comment: @PRATAP I want grub to manage all the booting stuff if possible, otherwise it is still a great solution to install two os seperately

Comment: Ya now i understood clearly. This may be off topic.. Don't you like to reinstall grub after installing Windows?

Comment: I think if you have two disks with two OS'es installed irrespective of order windows first or Ubuntu first but the opposite disk is not connected while installing OS'es. It's possible to give control to grub. Once you are on Ubuntu, simply update the GRUB while both disks are connected.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Windows is not designed to co-exist, it creates it's own boot record in the MBR by default, since it couldn't boot, otherwise. Here is an alternate solution, install Windows on it's own hard drive ***with no other hard drives attached.*** If you wish, you can do the same for Linux. Then, once that is done, reconnect your drives, and you can boot either one using your PC's bios boot menu, or just update your grub configuration. You need to make sure that the Windows drive is the first physical device though, since that is what it expects, and if it's out of order Windows may not boot. I've used this solution when desiring a dual boot computer where the operating systems are not "aware" of each other. Of course, Ubuntu will detect the Windows drive, but there is no need to mount it if it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** way that you can do that .

But to be honest its quite easy to reinstate grub after you've successfully installed windows 10 (or any version of windows for that matter ) alongside your ubuntu . What you'll need is a live usb / bootable usb of ubuntu and run these commands on the terminal of that live usb of ubuntu to successfully reinstate your grub 2 . I also followed the same procedure earlier and it worked for me . Here is the link for commands *https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd*
Hope this helps , let me know once you're done.